# Injective/Surjective Multi-variable function

Tags: functions, solution-verification

$f:\mathbb{Z}$ $\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x)=mx^3 - nx$, where $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I am trying to prove whether or not the function is injective or subjective. Is this proof sufficient?

Injectivity:

Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.
$ma^3-na = mb^3-nb \iff ma^3-mb^3 = na-nb \iff m(a^3-b^3) = n(a-b) \iff m(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=n(a-b)$.

Case 1) $a-b=0$. Then $a=b$

Case 2) $a-b \not= 0$. Then $m(a^2+ab+b^2)=n \iff a^2+ab+b^2 = \frac{n}{m}$. Contradiction.

Take case 1), then f is injective.

Surjectivity:

Suppose $f(a)=b$. Claim that $1 \notin im(f)$.
Therefore, $1= ma^3 - an = a(ma^2-n)$

Case 1) $a=ma^2-n=1$. Then $1=1(m-n)$ so $m=n+1$

Case 2) $a=ma^3-na=-1.$ Then $ 1=-1(m-n) = -m+n \iff n=1+m$

Therefore, f is not surjective.

Comment: Why does $m-n=1$ imply that $m=n$?

Comment: In any case, you need to make some more assumptions.  If $(m,n)=(0,-1)$ we have $f(x)=x$ which is certainly subjective.  So you need restrictions on $(m,n)$.

Comment: On the whole, it is very hard to follow what you wrote.  What conclusion are you trying to establish?

Comment: @lulu fixed the implication. I am trying to prove that the function is 1-1 but not onto.

Comment: But it is not generally  one to one.  If $(m,n)=(1,1)$ then $f(x)=x(x^2-1)$  And $f(0)=0=f(\pm 1)$.

Comment: There are many problems in this "proof" - Counterexamples can be worked out ; I prefer to read such examples by friends here.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some cases in your study, I would start with:

- $m=0$ and $n=0$ then $f(x)=0$ neither injective nor surjective.
- $m=0$  and $n\neq 0$ then $f(x)=-nx$ is monotonous therefore a bijection on $\mathbb R$.

Injectivity is kept on $\mathbb Z$ but surjectivity only for $n=\pm 1$ (i.e. $f(x)=1\implies x=-\frac 1n$).

- $m\neq0$  and $n=0$ then $f(x)=mx^3$ is monotonous therefore a bijection on $\mathbb R$.

Injectivity is kept on $\mathbb Z$ but surjectivity never happens

$f(x)=2\implies x=\sqrt[3]{\frac 2m}\implies m=\pm 2$

but then $f(x)=1\implies x=\sqrt[3]{\pm\frac 12}$ not an integer

Let now study the more general case when $f$ is not degenerated. Surjectivity will essentially fail due to the same reason as above with $mx^3$, injectivity is more delicate because the function may not be injective on $\mathbb R$ (due to non-monotonicity) but when restricted to integer inputs it may well be.

- $m=n\neq 0$ then $f(x)=m(x^3-x)$

$\require{cancel}f(a)=f(b)\iff \cancel{m}(a^3-a)=\cancel{m}(b^3-b)\iff (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2-1)=0$

We have either $a=b$ or $(a,b)\in\{(-1,0),(1,0),(0,-1),(0,1),(-1,1),(1,-1)\}$, so it is not injective because $f(0)=f(1)=f(-1)=0$.

- $m\neq n$ both non zero then $f(x)=mx^3-nx$

We can solve the case where it is injective on $\mathbb R$

$f'(x)=3mx^2-n$ which has root if $x^2=\frac n{3m}$.

So it is trivial for $n,m$ of opposite signs that $f$ is monotonous.

In the general case we are lead to study if there exists integer points on the curve $$a^2+ab+b^2=\frac nm>0$$

There are simple cases that can be proven non-injective e.g. $n=mk^2$ then $f(0)=f(k)=0$, but otherwise this is a difficult question to find integer points on elliptic curves.